# FLUTTER: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'TensorFlowLiteC.h' file not found

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, flutter, dart

My flutter project has `tflite:` dependency for running tflite model, But when I'm trying to build the iOS application it gives the above error.

It's working fine on android.

Following is my `Podfile` code

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  # use_frameworks! #add here
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

When I execute the command `flutter build ios` it gives the error like

```
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 937S4T5D4R
Running pod install...                                              6.3s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           17.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'TensorFlowLiteC.h' file not found
/Users/amventuresprivatelimited/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/tflite-1.1.2/ios/Classes/TflitePlugin.mm:19:8


Encountered error while building for device.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using [tflite_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter).
Try to follow the steps listed [here](https://github.com/am15h/tflite_flutter_plugin#ios) for iOS.
Basically, you need to add a compiled version of Tensorflow in the plugin pub cache folder. If you need to use the GPU Delegate you can follow the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_ios#build_tensorflowlitec_dynamic_framework_recommended) of Tensorflow.